# Namespace MongoDB\BSON and MongoDB\Drivers are missing

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I am learning PHP REST + MongoDb. I had installed mongodb PHP library using "composer require mongodb/mongodb".

But I am not able to use any type from *MongoDB\BSON\XXXXX*. Visual studio code says *MongoDB\BSON* is not even a package. I tried "use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime" but with no luck. [image: VSCode error]

I tried looking into package "mongodb/mongodb" under vendor's folder. In *functions.php*, I am facing the same issue.[image: MongoDb PHP library]

Without using package "MongoDB\BSON\XXXX", I am able to access data from database. So I don't think I am missing something major.

Am I missing something to install or configure?